# Javascript csw using toFixed is crashed by € symbol?

Tags: javascript

So I have this example:

```
function download() {
    const num = (11).toFixed(2);
    const content = [['Number'],[num + ' €']];
    const universalBOM = '\uFEFF';
    const csvContent = content.map((row) => row.join(',')).join('\r\n');
    const blob = new Blob([`${universalBOM}${csvContent}`], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
      
    link.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    link.setAttribute('download', `download.csv`);

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

download();
```

It should download a csw file containing `11.00 €` but it contains `1.100 €` and I don't know why. If I replace the `€` with any other character it will work.

So If I switch this line:

```
const content = [['Number'],[num + ' €']];
```

with this one:

```
const content = [['Number'],[num + ' $']];
```

It will display the correct value.

Any idea why this is happening ? Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/oqd2ukxt/)

Comment: Not sure why you got that result. When I tried the fiddle, the result contains `11.00 €` when opened using Microsoft Excel, and similarly it contains `11.00 €` when opened using Notepad++

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce - Numbers on Mac shows me `11.00 €` and `11.00 $`, respectively, when I opened the downloaded files.

Comment: I use numbers on Mac and I get 1.100 €. Let me get to my personal computer which is windows and test it out. But on this Mac for me it shows this stupid thing, I can make a video if necessary to prove.

Comment: Can you use a plain text editor to see the actual content of the CSV? If it has `11.00` then it's a problem with Numbers, not JS.
I wonder if it's because the system settings has "thousands separator" set to ".", so `11.00` is interpreted as the number `1100` (one thousand one hundred) which is then displayed as `1.100`? But it doesn't do the same for `$` as `11.00 $` is treated as a plain string, not a numerical value, as "$" is not auto-detected as currency (another thing to do with the system's regional settings).

Comment: If I open it with Text Edit it seems that I got 11.00 €. I was not expecting this. But why would Numbers display 1.100 € ? It is frustrating becuse if I try to make a presentation with my work the stakeholders will say that I have bugs in my code.

Comment: @paulalexandru LibreOffice Calc shows 11.00, maybe you could use that instead of Numbers

Comment: @paulalexandru another user above uses Numbers on Mac but it is loaded as expected. I think the difference should be the system settings (I'm not familiar with locale/system language settings in Mac though, but there should be a setting for "thousands separator" somewhere. Probably near the settings for "currency" and "decimal separator". And I'm not sure whether it's a language setting in the OS or specifically in Numbers)

Comment: Can you try the instructions for Mac in https://support.talkdesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047099811-CSV-Files-and-Regional-Settings ?

Comment: My Mac is Ventura 13.5.1 those do not work for me, but I found something in System Settings, searched after Language and Region and in the Applications sections I added a new application Numbers and set the default language from System English to my native language and it seems that did the job. Thank you

Comment: @CBroe how to handle this question now? "not reproducible or caused by a typo"?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
const num = (11).toFixed(2);
```

replace with

```
const num = (11).toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

With this change, the num variable is a string representation of 11.00, and it won't/ should't be be treated as having a thousands separator, ensuring that your CSV file contains 11.00 €

Comment: OP's code is working as expected, nobody seems to be able to reproduce their problem, and yet you are providing a useless solution based on... on what?

Comment: @GrafiCode - As the problem is not reproducible, I assumed the problem is local environment settings. If he use the .toLocaleString() method in JavaScript to format a number as a string, it respects the localization settings of your environment.[refe rence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: why should that be different, "11.00 €" is written in the CSV file as a string anyway